# ListViewから親ListFragmentを取得するには？

Tags: android, java, android-listfragment

androidアプリ開発で、ListFragmentを使用しています。
ListViewで使用する行要素(ViewHolder的なもの)やAdapterは外部クラスとして定義しています。
外部クラスからListFragmentを取得するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？
ContextやListViewを取得することはできたので、getFragmentManager().findFragmentByID()でもよいのですが、idを使用せず直接インスタンスを取得することはできないか？と思い質問致しました。

android、javaとも初心者の為、表現がおかしいかもしれませんが、ご指摘頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

独自AdapterのコンストラクタでListFragmentのインスタンスを受け取るようにすれば、出来るかと思います。

例

```
public class HogehogeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HogeItem> {

    private ListFragment listFragment;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public HogehogeAdapter(Context context, ListFragment listFragment, List<HogeItem> itemList) {
        super(context, 0, itemList);
        this.listFragment = listFragment;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: ListViewからは取得できないのですね。引数に渡す方法でいきたいと思います。ご回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: あ、回答が曖昧でしたね。ListViewからFragmentを取得するのは大変むずかしいと思います。

Comment: 「大変むずかしい」と分かり、すっきりしました。^^